# Flutter list search with url_launcher

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, search

I am trying to link each `data name` to a specific `url` and `data` are `filtered`. I tried getting the `url` by using `index` value but it will keep changing according to my search. A sample data example and `url` example is shown below for better understanding. I have a few topics and each topic has it own data name and `url` data, i will need a way to launch the correct `url` `onTap`. Thank you

**Data example**(data declared in `wordsList`)

```
Fruits:
Apple,
Orange,
Banana,
Pear

Color:
Red,
Blue,
Green,
Purple
```

**Url example**

```
https://example.com/fruits1.html
https://example.com/fruits2.html
https://example.com/fruits3.html
https://example.com/fruits4.html

https://example.com/colors1.html
https://example.com/colors2.html
https://example.com/colors3.html
https://example.com/colors4.html
```

**CODE**

```
 List<String> wordsList = [...];
  List<String> filteredWordsList = [];

void _onSearch(value) {
    setState(() {
      filteredWordsList =
          wordsList.where((item) => item.toLowerCase().contains('$value')).toList();
    });
  }
```

Here i declare data into the wordsList and filteredWordsList will pull out the list of data from wordsList upon searching.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
   child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: filteredWordsList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text('${filteredWordsList[index]}'),
                      onTap: (){
                    _launch('https://example.com/xxx$index.html');

                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Here i need to call the correct url.

```
Future<void> _launch(String url) async{
  
  
    if (await canLaunch(url)) { 
      
      await launch(url, forceSafariVC: true, forceWebView: true , enableJavaScript: true,); 
      
    } else { 
      throw 'Could not launch $url'; 
    } 
}
```

This is my url_launcher

Comment: you cannot use `_launch('https://example.com/xxx$index.html');` since it cannot depend on `index` - imagine your search result has always one item - so you would always use `example.com/xxx0.html` which is of course wrong

Comment: @pskink i know that this is the wrong way of calling the url, do u have any suggestions to solve this? Is there a way to bind the url and data together? Aside from this search feature, i have a UI that has all the data names linked to the respective url.

Comment: *"Is there a way to bind the url and data together? "* - `class WebSite {
final String name;
final String url;

WebSite(this.name, this.url);
}`

Comment: @pskink Thank you for the help, I am able to run my links properly now. :)